# VS 2015 MVC6 references/dependencies errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just upgraded my VS 2015 RC to the final version from MSDN.
Then I tried adding a new project, an MVC 6 project.

But nothing works, and the error list is empty.
If I try to build, it just seems to wait forever, and eventually I have to cancel the build process - no errors atall, it just doesn't build.
 - And rightfully so, since as you can see from the screenshot below, most of the references for both Core and DNX are marked with yellow error triangles.

But at least I would have liked some kind of error message or other hint on how to fix this.

I have made zero changes to the project, so it should have worked out of the box.
Except maybe the "WindowsAzure.Storage" reference, I think I added that one, but one more or less doesn't make any difference, I just wanted to see if any references I added myself via the nuGet manager would work better, but they don't.

[image: Most references show errors right out of the box]

Not sure if it will help, but here is a copy of the default project.json from the project in question:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.4.1-preview"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me either the new DNVM is not installed properly or the DNX core is missing. Try opening up a powershell window and type `dnvm`. You should see something like this:

[image]

Also, make sure you have the beta-5 DNX installed. You can check this by typing `dnvm -list` and you should get something along the lines of the lower part of this image:

[image]

The DNVM runtime should come with the web stuff in Visual Studio 2015. If you hadn't installed that, I don't think you would have been able to do file > new project for a new solution.

If you installed an older version of VS2015, maybe you got an older version of the DNX core and you need to upgrade. Use the `dnvm upgrade` command for this.

More info on installing DNVM: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html
For installing new DNX's: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005145/DNVM-DNX-and-DNU-Understanding-the-ASP-NET-Runtime

I hope this helps. I do recommend you get an idea of what DNVM and DNX mean and do, since it's going to be important if you want to do vNext stuff.

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I think we are on the right track, though the problem isn't solved yet :-(

When first I executed dnvm, I just got an error about running scripts being disabled.
I then executed the following commands, and that seemed to help:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`
`dnvm install -r coreclr latest`
`dnvm upgrade`

After that, my `dnvm list` now contains `1.0.0.-beta4`, beta5 and beta6 versions of both clr and coreclr for both x86 and x64.

Comment: But Visual Studio 2015 still has the yellow triangles everywhere. Only change is that when I try to build the project, the Output window now shows 137 errors instead of nothing, and it stops on it's own, instead of just hanging untill I cancel the build process. Sample error message (first error): `DNX 4.5.1 error : Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics >= 1.0.0-beta5 could not be resolved`

Comment: What is the selected DNX? Make sure you've selected beta5 as the selected DNX. You'll need to use `dnvm use [something]` for that. 
Also you can right click on the vNext project 'References' node - and click 'Restore Packages' - what happens ?

Comment: While searching for a solution for the problem with the dependency not being possible to resolve, I stumbled over this blog post: [http://iamnotmyself.com/...](http://iamnotmyself.com/blog/2015/07/22/dependency-could-not-be-resolved-error-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm/). It also mentions the command `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta5` followed by the command `dnu restore`. And that seems to do the trick. The `dnu restore` command timed out a few times, but after 3 tries, it completed a successful restore. Instead of yellow triangles, I now have nice nuGet icons, and no errors when compiling. SOLVED! Yes!